# Memory Error while calling genfromtxt method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Code :

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=sp.genfromtxt("data/train.tsv", delimiter ="\t", dtype="string", comments=None, skip_header=1)
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
x = x[~sp.isnan(y)]
y = x[~sp.isnan(y)]


DataOfInterest=x["avglinksize"]
EphemeralOrEvergreen=x["label"]
plt.scatter(DataOfInterest,EphemeralOrEvergreen)
plt.title("Training data")
plt.xlabel("Single feature from training set")
plt.ylabel("Ephemeral or Evergreen")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output :

python GenGraphs.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GenGraphs.py", line 4, in <module>
    data=sp.genfromtxt("data/train.tsv", delimiter ="\t", dtype="string", comments=None, skip_header=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1746, in genfromtxt
    output = np.array(data, dtype)
MemoryError
```

I am trying to graph one column in the tsv file against another.

What have I misunderstood here? How else can I do this ?

Comment: How big is `train.tsv`?

Comment: @mtitan8 It is available here : http://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/data . It is 20.6MB, with 27 columns and 7,396 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load it using a `np.memmap`, which will demand you about 70MB:

```
import numpy as np
with open('train.tsv') as f:
    mm = np.memmap('test.memmap', shape=(7395, 27), dtype='|S4000', mode='w+')
    f.next()
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        mm[i,:] = l.strip().replace('"','').split('\t')
```

The file is saved when you delete `m` with `del m` or when you close the Python console. Maybe you will have to change the mode to `r+` after the file is created.

You can work with the memmap array as if it was a normal array, which will allow you to take only the parts of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Python runs out of memory because the object you're trying to create is simply to big. The reason is that your data contains some very large strings (noticed this from your previous question).

The array `data` that you create only has a single `dtype`. The size of this dtype is chosen to be large enough to hold the longest string in your data. But regardless of the other content, for each field in the data the same amount of memory is allocated! For this reason the size in memory of the array can become much larger than the data file size!

As a solution you could specify the dtype for each column, but easier is to only load the data  that you actually need:

```
data = sp.genfromtxt('data/train.tsv', 
                     delimiter ='\t', 
                     names=True, 
                     usecols='avglinksize','label'))
```